# Is there a Gatling 1.5 JMS plugin?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, gatling

I would like to use the Gatling-JMS plugin on Gatling 1.5. I see that one that works on 2.0.0M3 but 2.0.0 is somewhat lacking in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of (I'm Gatling's project leader).